# Make tilde ~ character appear curved (KDE)

Tags: fonts, kde

I recently installed a (B)LFS system on my computer.

The tilde key (~) is shown as a straight line, much like the `em-dash` (-) in many locations, such as `konsole`, `kate` and also in the box that I am currently entering text (unlike the preview below, where it properly appears curved).

Similarly, it appears in a sensible fashion in firefox.

I assume that I have a problem with my font setup.

How should I change my configuration in order to get curved ~ characters in programs like `konsole`?

Comment: I think you are on the right track that it is a font issue.  Some fonts may not get the tilde rendered correctly, especially at low DPI or low font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use DejaVu Sans Mono in Konsole (Yakuake) and the tilde is correctly represented even at very small sizes (and/or low zoom values), but I recall this happening with other fonts. What fonts are you using?

EDIT: You can install the DeJaVu fonts in Ubuntu (and related distros) by doing

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-dejavu
```

Which is a meta package pulling in `ttf-dejavu-core` and `ttf-dejavu-extra`.

In other distros the package is also usually called `ttf-dejavu`.

I also use the DeJaVu Sans from the Infinality patchset. [Here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/better-font-rendering-in-linux-with.html) how to install it under Ubuntu, [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Infinality-bundle%2Bfonts) under Arch.

In KDE, you also have the opportunity to get fonts from the OpenDesktop.org database. Just do:
System Settings -> Font Management -> Get New Fonts
Common fonts are usually not there but there are a number of cool ones.

Comment: Thank you for the suggested font. I'll take a look when I get back to my system and try out the DejaVu Sans Mono to see if that improves matters.

Comment: Changing font to Courier (Adobe) gave me a nice curved tilde. I'd mark this as an answer, but it doesn't really answer the question and so isn't helpful for others so much. Can you edit it to explain the installation of (for example) DejaVu Sans Mono into a KDE system, and I'll mark it accepted?

Comment: I edited adding some general info on how to install fonts in KDE and how to install the dejavu set in some common distros. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks - I don't have a package manager like apt or pacman but this answer is definitely more useful now so marked as answered.